# Discarding Observations during time series analysis

Tags: r, time-series, arima, sas

I'm studying Economics and we use SAS as our programming software. What I did notice is that with the AR and MA process we usually work with 250 observations. What confuses me though is the lecturer always discards the first 50 observation when he wants to simulate an time series process. He said he does it to limit the influence of the starting values of the series. My question is why the first 50 observations would influence the data and why we would want to discard them to make our analysis more accurate.

Comment: This seems to be context specific. What kind of data is this?

Comment: Its just randomly generated data with seed=0. The only info the lecturer gives us is the AR or MA function, the mean and standard deviation of the white noise term and that the process is stationary

Comment: If the time series are generated randomly for the whole length then it makes no sense to discard a certain portion of it, the first 50 will behave the same as the last 50. Are you sure all points are generated randomly? Why did the professor mention starting values? How are they generated? Are these time series changing slowly?